# Find duplicate in excel with certain criteria

Tags: excel

I know, multiple questions has been asked with respect to duplicate in excel. However, I didnt find anything similar, so asking the same.

I have an excel consist of one columns which contains large set of records in the format below, say

XYZ/**123/456.abc.def.bla.ghi**

ABC/**985/klm_nop**

FGH/**999/mon.pqr.stu**

I want to compare for duplicate but by ignoring the first letter (till '/'). If it matches the highlighted part with any other set in the column then return me as a duplicate/highlight otherwise unique.

any help on this ?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question *is not how to find duplicates*, but **how to get rid of the first part of your records**.

You will achieve this with this formula: `=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,LEN(A1))` - assuming the first entry is in A1

Then you can use conditional formatting for duplicate values.